# Run playbook, pass host as arg but host is not present as an entry in /ansible/hosts

Tags: ansible

Is there any why to pass a hostname as an argument while running a playbook, and this hostname is not there in the /ansible/host file??

I did try

ansible-playbook -i hostname, playook.yml

Answer (score 0):

You can somewhere dynamically define variable hostname.

```
export hostname=myHostAddress
```

Then you create file "hosts" with defined $hostname and return its name. Then you limit invokation of playbook.yml just for you $hostname.

```
ansible-playbook -i $(echo "$hostname" > hosts %% echo "hosts -l $hostname") playook.yml
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your hosts is all or a variable in your playbook:

```
---
- name: Test
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: True

  tasks:
    - name: Debug
      debug:
        var: groups
```

Then run as:

```
ansible-playbook --inventory=windows, debug.yml
```

You will get:

```
PLAY [Test] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [windows]

TASK [Debug] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [windows] => {
    "groups": {
        "all": [
            "windows"
        ],
        "ungrouped": [
            "windows"
        ]
    }
}

PLAY RECAP ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************
windows                    : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Other option is using a variable and pass it at runtime:

So:

```
---
- name: Test
  hosts: "{{ host }}"
  gather_facts: True

  tasks:
    - name: Debug
      debug:
        var: groups
```

And do:

```
ansible-playbook  debug.yml -e host=windows
```

Besides that, you have the `add_host` or the `group_by` options